# How can I make the div's height equals the body's height with css?

Tags: css

I put hundreds of div elements into the body element.So the html and body's height both equals 7400px.
And I write the css for one of the divs like this;

```
#app{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -999;
}
```

I wish it's height equals 7400px too,while it's height equals the browser window's height which is 967px;
how can I make the #app element's heigt equals the html and body's height?
I tried to write like this.And then the html and body's heigt equal the browser's height.

```
    html{
      height: 100%;
    }
    body{
      height: 100%;
    }
```

How can I make the div's height equals the body's height with css?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a div 100% height of the browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window)

Comment: He's saying it is already the size of the window but wants it the full page height. That question does not answer what is being asked here. Vote to reopen

Comment: Do you want the '#app' element to have full height of the viewable screen size even when the screen height changes,its able to adjust it as per that. You want to do this only..right?

Comment: The answer is that he needs `position: relative` on the body/parent element

Comment: I want the #app element's height equals 7400px,How can I make that happen

Comment: @praveenkaushik Yes,any ideas?

Comment: @Jing My comment above should solve your issue

Comment: @abney317 I'm sorry,but that dosen't work

Comment: The parent would also need a fixed height. You said 7400px? So the body would need `height: 7400px` as well

Comment: It would help to clarify a lot if you can show us your HTML code. Have you considered: height: auto.

Comment: @abney317  It works  with setting the body's height as 7400px.How can make this with 
 dynamic height?

Comment: @ChongLipPhang `<div id="app"></div><div>111</div><div>111</div>` the html is just like this

Comment: @abney317 I solved this issue with this,`body{
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }` Thank you